# How to add a layer file to an ArcGIS map document programmatically?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, layers

I want to create a feature layer from a layer (.lyr) file and add it to my ArcGIS map document programmatically. I am using C# and ArcGIS.

I have a layer file and a shapefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a snippet for this in the ArcObjects .NET SDK: [Add Layer File to ActiveView Snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000050000000)

Comment: to use this we have to `add reference` of `ESRI Catalog UI Object Library` in visual studios project.